# Is there something equivalent of UIActivityViewController in OSX?

Tags: macos, uikit, osx-mavericks, appkit

I am migrating an application from iOS to OSX, Is there something equivalent of UIActivityViewController in OSX . For things like Facebook, Twitter, mail , Message sharing,  I need to do something like;

```
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString, shareImage, shareUrl, nil];


UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];


activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can you achieve this in OSX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For OSX , we can use the NSSharingServicePicker which is very similar to UIActivityViewController for iOS:

```
NSSharingServicePicker *sharingServicePicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:urls];
sharingServicePicker.delegate = self;

[sharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds]
                                      ofView:sender
                               preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

Comment: is there anything for watch OS?